# How to log 10 scale axis in ggscatter

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot a similar figure.

[image]

```
data(cars)
p <- ggscatter(cars, x = "speed", y = "dist")
p + yscale("log10", .format = TRUE)
```

I wanna use log10 to scale the axis, and then change the label.
How to make a figure as above?
[image]

Comment: Is setting `.format = FALSE` in `yscale` what you're looking for? Looks like it gives the desired output.

Comment: I wanna the axis is 1, 10, 100 instead of 10^0.5  10^1 10^2. I tried many ways to change it. Not work. Thanks!

Comment: If you want the range of the y-axis to be extended, isn't that just a case for `+ylim(...)` or maybe `scale_y_continuous`? (I found this in the closevote-queue but now am wondering if it's just a duplicate.)

Answer (score 2):

If you are not satisfied by `p + yscale("log10", .format = TRUE)`, you can also set the breaks manually:

```r
p + scale_y_log10(breaks = c(1,10,100), limits = c(1,120))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you're just trying to change the formatting of the labels, `scales::number_format()` may be a good option. You will also need to adjust the limits to include the breaks you want to see if they're outside the range of the data. In your example 1 won't show up if you don't extend the `limits` because the axis limits would be clipped closer to the data range by default.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(ggpubr)
library(scales)

data(cars)
p <- ggscatter(cars, x = "speed", y = "dist")
p + scale_y_log10(labels = number_format(accuracy = 1), 
                  breaks = 10^(0:2),
                  limits = c(1, 100))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-12-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>